# How can I solve this recursion function task?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, recursive-algorithms, recursion

I really need help on this task. Im stuck at it and I really would appreciate your help here.

> *Give a recursive function $r$ on $A$ that reverses a string. For instance, $r(logikk) = kkigol$ and $r(moro) = orom$. (given that $A$
> the amount of letters in the Norwegian alphabet which has 29 letters.
> ). Define the function in such a way that it is correctly regardless
> of what $A$ are.*

$logikk$ means $logic$ in norwegian, and $moro$ means $fun$ in norwegian in case you're wondering.

Edit:

I think i've figured out one of the recursive functions:

> $r(\Lambda) = \Lambda$ (empty string)
>
> $r(l) = r(a) + o$
>
> $r(o) = r(l) + g$
>
> $r(g) = r(o) + i$
>
> $r(i) = r(g) + k$
>
> $r(k) = r(i) + k$
>
> $r(k) = r(k)$

Can someone please check if this is correct for $r(logikk)$ I feel like i'm missing something but i'm not sure what.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: The recursion is on the length of the string. That is, if $w$ is a word and $\alpha$ is a letter, the recursion step of the definition should tell you how to construct $r(w\alpha)$ if you already know $r(w)$. For example, it should tell you that if $r(w)=\text{låm}$, then $r(w\text{e})=\text{elåm}$. (If you prefer nynorsk, you can make that $r(w\text{a})=\text{alåm}$!) You can get the recursion started by defining $r(\epsilon)$, where $\epsilon$ is the empty word.

Comment: please check my edit and see if i've done one of them correctly

Comment: @Dabbish: I’m afraid that you’ve badly misunderstood what $r$ is supposed to do. The function $r$ is supposed to reverse the letters in the input word, so $r(\text{g})=\text{g}$, $r(\text{o})=\text{o}$, and in fact if $\alpha$ is any letter, then $r(\alpha)=\alpha$. Thus, your $r$ is giving the wrong results. It’s also completely tied to the specific word *logikk*, when it’s supposed to work on *any* possible input. Your base is correct, but for the recursive step you’ll actually need only one line: for any word $w$ and letter $\alpha$, $r(w\alpha)=$ ... what?

Comment: hmm, what about this 

$\Lambda =$ The empty string, $r(\Lambda) =$ $\Lambda$, $r(k) = k$, $r(k) = k$, $r(i) = i$, $r(g) = g$, $r(o) = o$, $r(l) = l$ would that be more correct? I am not so sure about the on line part but i'll try , $r(wa) = wa$

Comment: @Dabbish: Your definition need not have any provisions for single letters. The base case is $r(\Lambda)=\Lambda$. Then there is a one-line recursion step that of the form $r(w\alpha)=\text{something}$.

Comment: still can't figure i. I would appreciate it if you could give me an answer. I think i'll learn much better out from that then.

Comment: @Dabbish: Let’s try once more; if you don’t get it from this question, I’ll simply give you the answer. When you add a letter to the righthand end of $w$, what happens to the reversal? You add that same letter ... where?

Comment: You add that same letter to the left hand? $r(wa) = r(aw)$?

Comment: @Dabbish: Yes, and no, in that order. You want $r(w\alpha)=\alpha r(w)$ for any word $w$ and letter $\alpha$. The idea is to say how to construct the reversal of the longer word if you already know the reversal of the shorter one.

Comment: Doh! Almost, hehe. Really, thanks a lot for you time and patience, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Dabbish: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion here.

Write $A^*$ for the set of all words in the alphabet $A$ (ie finite sequences of elements of $A$). Write $A^{\leqslant n}$ for the set of all words in the alphabet $A$ of length $\leqslant n$. $A*$ is a monoid for the concatenation $\star$ defined by :
$$ (u_i)_{i\leqslant n} \star (v_j)_{j \leqslant m} := (u_1, \dots, u_n, v_1, \dots, v_m)$$

Say you have a function $f_n : A^{\leqslant n} \mapsto A^{\leqslant n}$ that reverses all words of length $\leqslant n$. Then you can define $f_{n+1} : A^{\leqslant n+1} \mapsto A^{\leqslant n+1}$ as follow for $\mathbf{u} = (u_i)_{i \leqslant m}$ :

$$ f_{n+1}(\mathbf{u}) := \left\lbrace \begin{array}{cl} f_n(\mathbf{u}) & \textrm{ if } m\leqslant n\\ u_{n+1}\star f_n\big((u_1,\dots, u_n) & \textrm{ if } m = n+1\end{array} \right.$$

By definition, $f_{n+1}$ coincides with $f_n$ on $A^{\leqslant n}$. Now you can define (thr graph of) your function $reverse: A^* \mapsto A^*$ as follow :
$$ reverse := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n $$